# Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported

Tags: mysql, distributed-transactions

I am Using a transaction scope. Within that transactionscope, i have a mysql database connection. However, I will need to open up a new [yet another] MySQL connection withing the previous transaction scope.

When I do so, i get the following error `Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported.`.

Is this because MySQL Server does not support Multiple Distributed Transactions, Is there anything that I should change in code or anything that i should change in the server?.

Will there be a support if i am using the above scenario with both connections being made to SQL Server instead of mysql server

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about [Two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) and it looks like MySQL is supporting it with [MySQL XA Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me go through these documentations and then leave you my feedback on how i work out things.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never tried this myself for MySql, I would expect this to be possible provided you can create an XA capable datasource.

[This question](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17734)  seems to imply that MySql does support XA.

One issue that you may then encounter is that you need to be running in an environment capable of dealing with XA transactions.  (in effect you are doing a distributed transaction across two databases because you are using two separate connections) I'm used to working in a Java EE App Server and so the server acts as the transaction coordinator, I'm not sure what would happen in a stand-alone Java program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to XA as like what you said. I'll revert back with details.